# show a popup on click a jquery search result

Tags: jquery

i have made a simple search form that uses jquery to display results but on click of the search results nothing happens except it is a link (that is a new page will be loaded into the browser).
Actually, i want to show more details inside a box

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form').submit(function(){
    var keyword = $('#text').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'search.php',
      data: keyword,
      success: function(result){`enter code here`
        $('div#result').html(result);
      }    
    });
  });

  // this is for a click on a result
  $('#visit').click(function(){
    // show my hidden box with more details in it
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you also provide the html code of the form? And may be what is in the result output variable? Does #visit appear in it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's appended content, so use event delegation:

```
$('#result').on('click', '#visit', function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: To expand on this a bit... submit() will only bind event handler to nodes which were present in the DOM at the time $(document).ready() was called.   Since '#form' is added after this point, it has no submit() handler assigned. Use .on() to attach the delegator to an element which will always be present, so that the event will bubble up the hierarchy and be handled there instead

Comment: it is not working. well i did it this way $('#result').on('click', '#visit', function(){
    alert('');
 });